# Grabbing data from certain files

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have ~200 files and would like to grab the data in each file, then to show all the data in one `.csv` file.

For example, the file list is

```
#targeted folder
a001.opd
a002.opd
a003.opd
...
..
.
a200.opd
```

Each file has the same data structure which looks like

```
model <many spaces>          1 <many spaces>       0.003    0.002  # Title
mo(data,1) <many spaces>     1 <many spaces>       0.2      0.0001 # 1
mo(data,1) <many spaces>     2 <many spaces>      -0.1      0.04   # 2
mo(data,1) <many spaces>     3 <many spaces>      -0.4      0.005  # 3
....................................
................
.............                                                      # n-1
......                                                             # n
```

If I would like to see something in my `grab_result.csv` file, does anyone how to achieve this by python.

```
#grab_result.csv  # order will be from left to right that is a001 to a200

a001                                      a002                                             
model      1 0.003 0.002  <empty column>  model      1  0.02   0.1   <empty column> 
mo(data,1) 1 0.2   0.0001 <empty column>  mo(data,1) 1  0.04   0.001 <empty column>
mo(data,1) 2 -0.1  0.04   <empty column>  mo(data,1) 2 -0.145  0.014 <empty column>
mo(data,1) 3 -0.2  0.003  <empty column>  mo(data,1) 3 -0.24   0.06  <empty column>
```

Below is the code I have done.

```
import os

def openfolder(path, outputfile='grab_result.csv'):  # get .opd file from folder and open an output file
    if os.path.isdir(path): 
        fo = open(outputfile, 'wb')
        fo.write('filename') # write title here
        for filename in [os.path.abspath(path)+'\\'+each for each in os.listdir(path) if each.endswith('.opd')]:                         
            return openfile(filename)
    else:
        print "path unavailable"

    openfolder('C:\\path', 'C:\\path\\grab_result.csv')     


def openfile(filename):   # open file.opd
    if os.path.isfile(filename) and filename.endswith('.opd'): 
        return grabdata(open(filename, 'rb').read())         
    else:
        print "invalid file"
        return []       


def grabdata(string):   # start to grab data
    ret = []
    idx_data = string.find('model')
    # then I stop here....
```

Does anyone know how to grab the data from these files?

Here is my example file ( http://goo.gl/HyT0wM )

Comment: you might not want the `openfolder('C:\\path', 'C:\\path\\grab_result.csv') ` inside the openfolder function, unless you want an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have many files with lots of content, I would use generators. That allows not to load all the contents into memory. Here is how I would go about it:

```
def get_all_files(path):
    ## get a generator with all file names
    import os
    import glob
    return glob.iglob(os.path.join(path,'*.opd'))

def get_all_data(files):
    ## get a generator with all the data from all the files
    for fil in files:
        with open(fil, 'r') as the_file:
            for line in the_file:
                yield line

def write_lines_to_file(lines, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w') as the_file:
        for line in lines:
            ## add here an if statement if not all lines should be written to outfile
            the_file.write(line+'\n')

path = 'blah blah'
outfile = 'blah.csv'
files = get_all_files(path)
lines = get_all_data(files)
write_lines_to_file(lines, outfile)
```

Comment: Honestly I have to say the program is elegant and quicker than mine! And may I know if I'd like to add the **file name** (a001, a002.....etc) in the first line _(as the title)_ of my outfile.csv, I mean as the title before my each data, do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks. To add the file name before each data, you can yield the file name before yielding all of the file content => add the following line after the line `for fil in files:` in get_all_data(): `yield fil`. You can change that to any string you would like instead of or I n addition to the file name.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
def grabdata(filename): 
    # start to grab data 
    matches = []
    with open(filename) as f:            
        for line in f:
            # add if matches:
            if line.startswith("model"): # or: line.find("model") != -1
                matches.append(line.strip())
    return matches
```

Comment: you can skip the `lines = f.readlines()` and iterate over the file object (so, you don't put the entire file into memory)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just an extended comment.

Why do you want the results from left to right (200 x 5 columns wide)?  Wouldn't it provide more flexibility for adding additional columns later if you were to transpose your data?  For example:

```
a001   model   mo(data,1)   mo(data,1)   mo(data,1)
         1          1           2            3
         0.003      0.2        -0.1         -0.2
         0.002      0.0001      0.04         0.003

a002   model   mo(data,1)   mo(data,1)   mo(data,1)
         1          1           2            3
...
```

The difficulty in having it 200 x 5 columns wide is that you need to pad columns.  If a file were missing information, then it could throw off your entire structure.  You also need to write each row consisting of a single slice from all 200 files.