# How could I grab file from many sub-folder via main folder?

Tags: python, python-2.7, directory

If I have a main folder and many sub-folders, and my targeted files are located at these sub-folders. How could I set up my path properly then the program could grab these targeted files via my main folder directly?

For example,

```
Main_folder
>sub_1
>>sub_1_v1
>>>targeted_file.txt  # file I need
>>sub_2_v2
>>>targeted_file.txt  # file I need
>sub_2
>>sub_1_v1
>>>targeted_file.txt  # file I need
>>sub_2_v2
>>>targeted_file.txt  # file I need
```

Here is a program created by Julien Spronck ([Grabbing data from certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189178/grabbing-data-from-certain-files))

```
def get_all_files(path):
    ## get a generator with all file names
    import os
    import glob
    return glob.iglob(os.path.join(path,'*.txt'))

def get_all_data(files):
    ## get a generator with all the data from all the files
    for fil in files:
        with open(fil, 'r') as the_file:
            for line in the_file:
                yield line

def write_lines_to_file(lines, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'w') as the_file:
        for line in lines:

            the_file.write(line+'\n')

path = 'blah blah' # path should be given here!
outfile = 'blah.csv'
files = get_all_files(path)
lines = get_all_data(files)
write_lines_to_file(lines, outfile)
```

My question is, how could I give the path properly (from main folder) then I can  grab all targeted files at one time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over folders, then files, use:

```
import os                                                                                                             

def list_files(dir):                                                                                                  
    r = []                                                                                                            
    subdirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]                                                                            
    for subdir in subdirs:                                                                                            
        files = os.walk(subdir).next()[2]                                                                             
        if (len(files) > 0):                                                                                          
            for file in files:                                                                                        
                r.append(subdir + "/" + file)                                                                         
    return r
```

As seen here:

[Python: Iterate through folders, then subfolders and print filenames with path to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19932441/838992)